# Can I block calls based on a specific number prefix or pattern?

Tags: call-screening

Is it possible to block calls starting with a specific number? For instance, I want to block calls from numbers starting with 1408 as they are all spam calls. The digits following these four, keep changing.

Answer (score 33):

If you're looking for a free *and* ad-free/in-app-purchase-free app, you can use the open-source [NoPhoneSpam](https://gitlab.com/bitfireAT/NoPhoneSpam/), which is available on F-Droid (though not Google Play). It supports blocking calls from individual numbers and from numbers that match a pattern with wildcards.

This is especially useful for blocking "prefix spoofing" calls, that appear to start with the area code and exchange (next 3 digits) of your phone number, but really are from random law-breaking telemarketer bots.

Comment: That website has a link to Google Play but when you click on that link Google Play says it does not recognize it. Searching on Google Play for "nophonespam" does not reveal anything of that specific named app..

Comment: Looks like it isn't in the Play Store at the moment. Someone should probably report that to the developer at https://gitlab.com/bitfireAT/NoPhoneSpam/issues

Answer (score 6):

[TrueCaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller) also allows this. Steps to take on an Android phone:

1. Open TrueCaller
2. Settings
3. Block
4. View my block list
5. Press the plus button in bottom-right
6. Block a number series
7. Enter the first six of your number

Comment: Be aware that Truecaller collects your data, your contacts and shares it with third parties including spammers and companies

Answer (score 4):

I only found ONE call blocker that is capable to block patterns (which is important for me). It is [embware Call Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=embware.phoneblocker), it can block or enable numbers with Match criteria: starts with, ends with, or include specific numbers.

Answer (score 2):

1. install F-Droid (FOSS/Open Source store) https://f-droid.org/docs/Get_F-Droid/
2. install [NoPhoneSpam](https://gitlab.com/bitfireAT/NoPhoneSpam/) by searching from F-Droid
3. add rules from within the app to block the blocs needed in your country, for France:

- France: : `0162, 0163, 0270, 0271, 0377, 0378, 0424, 0425, 0568, 0569, 0948, 0949`
- Guadeloupe, Saint-Martin et Saint-Barthélemy : `09475`
- Guyane : `09476`
- Martinique : `09477`
- La Réunion and Mayotte : `09478` and `09479`